# The meaning of "האב שמחל על כבדו כבדו מחול"?

Tags: halacha-theory, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

This is a follow-up question to "[does-mechilah-invalidate-kibud-av"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97200/does-mechilah-invalidate-kibud-av).

The Gemmorah in [Kiddushin 32](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.32a.15?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he) states:

> "א"ר יצחק בר שילא א"ר מתנה אמר רב חסדא **האב שמחל על כבודו כבודו מחול**"

Translating מחילה into English is tricky, it could mean "forgiveness" or "absolution". The difference it like דחויה or הותרה, in other words, it can mean that the כבוד exists but the father only "frees the son from the punishment" or that the father's כבוד is annulated by him so no Mitzvah of Kibbud can exist.

The first approach is backed by Radva"z and Sefer Chassidim, see [Chortkov's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97205/15579), the other is backed by Rashb"A (1:18), see [David's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97209/15579).

We use the term מחילה in various other situations, e.g. in monetary conducts (מחילת חוב) or as forgiveness for misdeeds.

What is the Halacha considering the מחילה - is it "total" or "partial"?

Comment: Is your question about whether the Radvaz or Rashba are correct?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות seemingly, there are only two approaches that I presented, but I am opened to others. I would also know if someone else discusses those approaches.